# How to use non-standard variable names in Java for producing XML tags?

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb

I am trying to write the AndroidManifest.xml file programmatically through Java using Jaxb. The problem comes while defining the attributes, which follow a string:string naming convention. For example, the manifest element is defined thus:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```

While doing this from Java, I cannot annotate the attributes because xmlns:android etc are not valid Java variables.

What is the best way to overcome this, while still using Jaxb, and not resorting to StringBuilder technique for generating the XML?

Comment: What is the java implementation you have started/tried?

Comment: As I said, I am trying to do it with Jaxb. So I have no problems defining the root and its sub elements, but with attributes, I am stuck because they dont follow Java variable naming conventions.

Comment: [Specify the namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html#namespace--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the javadoc of javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement:

```
  @XmlElement(name="item-price")
  public java.math.BigDecimal price;
```

The name parameter is what you'll see in the XML.

But this android: the namespace prefix and should appear according to the namespace definition, which is the parameter of namespace:

```
  @XmlElement(name="item-price", namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")
  public java.math.BigDecimal price;
```

After marshalling, you'll most likely see "ns1:" in place of android:, but that's OK.

Easiest way to get the annotated Java code: Write (or find) the XML schema and run it through `xjc`. Works all the time - almost ;-)

Comment: Yes, the name parameter also works with @XmlAttribute annotations. Thank you!